# How to revert the changes made by Selenium Nunit (C#) test from Database

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testing, nunit, database-connection

I am working on Selenium Nunit with C# for testing a web application. We have a Separate database for testing but the problem is the functional manual testers also uses the same database I am also using that same testing database.Do i need to create a separate database for Selenium Automation ? If Yes, Then how can I do that? we Are using Microsoft Sql Server. My Second question is, How can we revert the changes back which are done by my selenium script from the database. All my test scenarios are like add,edit,delete & fill the form.When i Execute my test the data gets stored into the database, and the test fail while running the same test for another time(bcz the same data is already present and i can not enter the duplicate data). I done a research and found some Solutions like :- 1) database back up and restore, 2) transaction and roll back, 3) use empty database and feed the data prior test run and use that data to work on test. But,I dont know which way to would be good for my requirement? Can anybody help me here?

I have not tried anything yet.

Comment: Do you actually need to maintain the stored test data after the test is finished? I assume you are performing integration tests since you are using a real database (MS SQL Server in your case).

My point is that the test should be as much isolated as possible and each test should ideally set up test data in the arranging phase, execute the tested action, verify results are as expected in the assertion phase and then clean-up the data. With physical database on the SQL Server it may get tricky because you would have to record what was added for the test.

Comment: As yourself mentioning in your last sentence "But,I dont know which way to would be good for my requirement?" We also don't know whats best for your environment and requirements. All your options might work. Simply exchanging the database files (mdb's) in between test for a reset is also an option.

Comment: The Q&A format of this community requires questions focus on a single problem. This question is far too broad as it is currently worded. Can you [edit] your question to focus on a single problem, including a [repro]?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn to reset you database back to a clean state.

hope this would help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I might not be getting the full picture but since you are using Selenium to test a web application in the staging phase (probably) you might not be able to replace the database at all because the app is deployed and running somewhere. Replacing a DB or resetting it may affect the work of the manual testers that target the same web application instance.

You might consider using some fake data generator for your test scripts. This might help you prevent the problem with conflicting data. I have used the Bogus for .NET NuGet package in some of my tests.